I'm unable to map the email with the activity using send email action in screen flow





I am creating an email activity using Screen Flow. My task is to select multiple accounts in the "Related To" component in the flow and send emails to them when I click the "Next" button. I am able to send the emails as well. Additionally, I have created two accounts: 'Test Account Cube84' and 'Test Account 2.' However, I'm only able to map one account in the email activity and not the other. What could be the possible solutions to resolve this issue?
